# MahApps.Metro change ToggleSwitch style

Tags: wpf, styles, mahapps.metro, toggleswitch

I'm testing wpf applications using MahApp.Metro.
Somehow I'm not able to change the style of the ToggleSwitch. I just want to change simple properties like foreground or background of the switch. What am I doing wrong?

Mainwindow.xaml

```
<Style  x:Key="flyoutToggleSwitchStyle" TargetType="{x:Type Controls:ToggleSwitch}" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type Controls:ToggleSwitch}}">
        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="WhiteSmoke"/>
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="White"/>    
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Yellow"/>
        <Setter Property="OnLabel" Value="Yes"/>  <!--<<<---THIS WORKS!!-->
        <Setter Property="OffLabel" Value="No"/>
    </Style>

<Controls:ToggleSwitch Style="{StaticResource flyoutToggleSwitchStyle}">
    <Controls:ToggleSwitch.Header>
           <TextBlock>
                    Test                            
           </TextBlock>
     </Controls:ToggleSwitch.Header>
 </Controls:ToggleSwitch>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Now there is a new `ToggleSwitch` property called `SwitchForeground` which allows changing the colour for `ON` position (tested on v0.14).
Example:

```
<controls:ToggleSwitch SwitchForeground="{StaticResource MyGreen}" />
```

Comment: Note: this property is now obsolete, one should use OnSwitchBrush / OffSwitchBrush

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that in the Mahapps.Metro ToggleSwitch most of the properties can not be changed within a style, because there is no TemplateBinding or Key defined in the original template definition. 
So the style can only be changed by creating a new template. For this the ToggleSwitch and the ToggleSwitchButton templates have to be changed.

[Issue on GitHub](https://github.com/MahApps/MahApps.Metro/issues/457)
[Source of the templates](https://github.com/MahApps/MahApps.Metro/blob/master/MahApps.Metro/Themes/ToggleSwitch.xaml#L100)